# Storing Arrays of object in local storage using ReactHooks and React.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I am facing an issue when adding the object to local storage, i have dig around a bit and came to know that we have to use `stringify` in order to store objects(local storage) otherwise it will be stored as an string.

It works fine for one object but when a new object comes in it will replace it with the new one rather than adding as another object(in local storage), so basically i am looking to achieve as below and saving in `localStorage`,

- when we receive the 1st object, then `basketItems/LocalStorage` will be `[{obj1}]`
- when we receive the 2nd object, then `basketItems/LocalStorage` will be `[{obj1},{obj2}]`
- and so on....

i have tired few ways including spread operator but cant really figure out a way to do it,any suggestion guys. Thanks

Note: `addBasketitems`, is a function that passes the object info from child(Home) to parent(App)

```
let initialvalue = () => {
  return window.localStorage.getItem("user-basket");
};
function App() {
  const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState(initialvalue);

  const addBasketitems = (product, quantity) => {
        setBasketItems((prevItems) => {
  const newItems = [...prevItems, { ...product, quantity }];
  window.localStorage.setItem("user-basket", JSON.stringify(newItems));
  return newItems;
}); 

// it works fine but return single object only when new object received then it just replace with existing one rather then add another object in an array
      };

  return (
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <header className="header">
      <Nav userinfo={userData} userstatus={siginalready} />
    </header>

    <div className="main">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={(props) => <Home {...props} addBasketitems={addBasketitems} />}
        />

        <Route
          path="/basket"
          exact
          render={(props) => (
            <Basket
              {...props}
              userData={userData}
              userstatus={siginalready}
              basketItems={basketItems}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>

    <div className="footer">
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

);
}

Comment: Get the data from local storage using JSON.parse , add the new object and set back using JSON .stringify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are always saving an object to local storage.

This line:

```js
JSON.stringify({ ...product, quantity })
```

Needs to be the following, and move it into the callback of `setBasketItems`:

```js
setBasketItems((prevItems) => {
  const newItems = [...prevItems, { ...product, quantity }];
  window.localStorage.setItem("user-basket", JSON.stringify(newItems));
  return newItems;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Enijar, i have tried to change as above(also updated the code above) but now it is coming up with compile error , saying, 'prevItems' is not defined. not sure why unless i am missing something.

Comment: I've updated my example. You need to move my previous example into the body of your `setBasketItems` function. I've shown this in my updated example.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, i have updated the code above and tried to execute this in my code but its now coming up with TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)), i am still a bit new to react/javascript, so not sure what exactly that means but  my guess is that it might be because of the initiavalue in useState(initialvalue()) that is set to null i think by default, i have tried to tweak it a bit but still no success, not sure what else i can change.

Comment: i have done some more digging and when console.log(prevItems) and it shows the value null, my guess is the initailvalue of state is null and thats why it is not iterable. the only thing i can think of is to set initialvalue first, but how can we set to other then null when it is out side the  App function unless if there is a workaround for this kind of issue.